# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne error in my springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my **Course.java** class, A topic can have multiple classes. When I run my program I get two exceptions, one is BeanCreationException & the other is AnnotationException. I'm attaching below all the classes of my code with the spring console log.

```
package com.shashank.courses;
import topic.Topic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Course {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

// There can be many courses under the topics
@ManyToOne
private Topic topic;

public Course() {

}

public Course(String id, String name, String description, String topicId) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.topic = new Topic(topicId, "", "");
}

public String getId() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {

    this.description = description;
}

public Topic getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}
}
```

This is my **CourseController.java**

```
package com.shashank.courses;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import topic.Topic;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class CourseController {

@Autowired
private CourseService courseService;

@RequestMapping("/topics/{id}/courses")
public List<Course> getAllCourses(@PathVariable String id) {
    return courseService.getAllCourses(id);
}

// {} for variable portion
@RequestMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
public Optional<Course> getCourse(@PathVariable String id) {
    return courseService.getCourse(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics/{topicId}/courses")
public void addCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable String topicId) {
    course.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "",""));
    courseService.addCourse(course);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
public void updateCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable String topicId, @PathVariable String id) {
    course.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "",""));
    courseService.updateCourse( course);
}

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}")
     public void deleteCourse(@PathVariable String id) {
    courseService.deleteCourse(id);
}
}
```

This is my **CourseService.Java**

```
package com.shashank.courses;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CourseService {

@Autowired
private CourseRepository courseRepository;

public List<Course> getAllCourses(String topicId) {

    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    courseRepository.findByTopicId(topicId).forEach(courses::add);
    return courses;
}

public Optional<Course> getCourse(String id) {
    return courseRepository.findById(id);
}

public void addCourse(Course course) {
    courseRepository.save(course);
}

public void updateCourse(Course course) {
    courseRepository.save(course);
}

public void deleteCourse(String id) {
    courseRepository.deleteById(id);
}
}
```

This is my **CourseRepository.java**  Interface

```
package com.shashank.courses;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, String> {

public List<Course> findByTopicId(String topicId);
}
```

This is my **Topic.java** class

```
package topic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

public Topic() {
}

public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {

    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Here is my Spring Console log

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 
'debug' enabled.
2021-03-04 16:23:05.108 ERROR 14500 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init 
method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on 
com.shashank.courses.Course.topic references an unknown entity: topic.Topic

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on 
com.shashank.courses.Course.topic references an unknown entity: topic.Topic
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**com.shashank.courses.Course.topic references an unknown entity: topic.Topic:** this means that Spring Boot can't find the Topic entity, so it can't create the Course entity because of the ManyToOne relation, so the app won't start because has a BeanCreationException.

Looking at your code, I can see that the Topic class is inside the "topic" package, but every other class/interface is inside the "com.shashank.courses" package.

Assuming you are using "com.shashank.courses" package as the main package for the application, Spring Boot is scanning this package to create the beans it needs. But since the Topic class is in a different package, it can't create the Topic bean.

If this is the case then you have two options:

1. Move the topic class to the "com.shashank.courses" package.
2. Use a correct @EntityScan annotation on your class that has the @SpringBootApplication.

Source: https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a collection of `Course` on your topic class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic")
private List<Course> courseList;
```

Also change your field with @ManyToOne annotation with this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "topic_id", nullable = false)
private Topic topic;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the relation you need a sintax like this:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
private List<Items> items;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
private Cart cart;
```